# Expressing the sine function in terms of exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, exponential-function

> Prove $e^{iz} - e^{-iz} = \sin z$.

I used 
$$\begin{align*}
\sin z & = z - z^3/3! + z^5/5! - z^7/7! + \dots  & (i) \\
e^{iz} & = 1 - z^2/ 2! - iz^3/3! + \dots & (ii) \\
e^{-iz} & = 1 - z^2/ 2! + iz^3/3! +z^4/4! + \dots & (iii)
\end{align*}$$

However, I couldn't get the subtraction of $(iii)$ from $(ii)$ to yield $\sin z$.

Comment: I've edited your question to use MathJax. Please verify that it is still the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to write series
with a summation sign
rather than individual terms.

In this case,
$e^x 
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
e^{ix} 
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(ix)^n}{n!}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(ix)^{2n}}{(2n)!}
+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(ix)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}
+i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\
\end{array}
$

From this,
putting $-x$ for $x$
and noting that
$(-x)^{2n} = x^{2n}$
and
$(-x)^{2n+1} = -x^{2n+1}$,

$e^{-ix} 
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}
-i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
$

If we add these,
$e^{ix}+e^{-ix} 
= 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}
=2 Cos(x)
$
and
$e^{ix}-e^{-ix}
= 2i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
= 2i Sin(x)
$.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{iz}-e^{-iz}=\sin(z)$ is false.

The correct formula is $$\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=\sin{z}$$

Also, your formulas (ii) and (iii) are missing the first-order terms.  The correct equations are:

$$e^{iz}=1+iz-\frac{z^2}{2}-i\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots$$
$$e^{-iz}=1-iz+\frac{z^2}{2}+i\frac{z^3}{3!}-\cdots$$

See if you can go from there.